# phantom process on MAC and cannot restart

Tags: mac, macos-highsierra

I try to install update for XCode and high sierra 10.13.2

However, there is phantom process which I cannot restart.

All the sql-developer process is gone  but somehow it thinks its still there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can force kill the process through terminal `killall SQLDeveloper`<sup>1</sup>.
Then proceed to restart

To get to your original objective which I interpreted as 'restarting your macOS'.

Related: 
[macOS - Mac App SQLDeveloper stuck in Dock after application closed, Process killed - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243671/mac-app-sqldeveloper-stuck-in-dock-after-application-closed-process-killed)

<sup>1</sup><sub>Forcefully killing processes can have unintended side-effects.</sub>

Comment: I did a hard reboot: sudo su - reboot now it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo su -
reboot now
```

It works doing a hard reboot on terminal